# Spark Structured Streaming - Graceful shutdown using a touch file

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on spark Structured Streaming which is pretty easy use case.

I will be reading data from Kafka and persist in hdfs sink after parsing JSON.

I have almost completed the part. Now problem is we should have good way of shutting down the streaming job without having to close abruptly (ctrl+c or yarn -kill).

I have used the below options 
`sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown","true")` but no use.

My requirement is when streaming job is running, it should get stop when some touch file is created in hdfs or Linux EN path.

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-demo-StreamingQueryManager-awaitAnyTermination-resetTerminated.html

In this above link, they create thread for fixed duration. But I need something like that which comes out of execution when some dummy file is created.

I am a newbie, so please need your help for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if actually works currently `sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown","true")`. Some claim it does work, though some don't.

- In any event it is about direct kill or graceful stopping.
- You need to kill the JVM though, or if in Databricks they have a whole lot of utilities.

But you will not lose data due to check-pointing and write ahead logs that Spark Structured Streaming provides. That is to say ability to recover state and offsets without any issues, Spark maintains own offset management. So, how you stop it seems less of an issue which may explain the confusion & the `"but no use".`